# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException after update to spring boot 2.2.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

I face a strange issue after upgrading my existing code from spring boot 2.2.0 to 2.2.1.
It seems that my spring data jdbc repositories are not getting scanned anymore somehow:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'de.thd.dmpk.establishmentmanagement.IEstablishmentRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Furthermore this informational debug line is there as well with boot 2.2.1:

```
Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface de.thd.dmpk.establishmentmanagement.IEstablishmentRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
```

When i switch everything back to boot 2.2.0 the info message as well as the exceptions above are disappearing.

Any hints?

**EDIT**
**Entity**

```
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName = "of", access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC, onConstructor = @__({@PersistenceConstructor}))
@EqualsAndHashCode
public final class Establishment {

private final @Id
@With
long establishmentId;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@Size(max = 255)
private final
String establishmentName;
}
```

**Repository**

```
interface IEstablishmentRepository extends CrudRepository<Establishment, Long>
```

Up to now a `@Table` Annotation was not necessary if you don´t want to change the table name on the db. Furthermore `@EnableJdbcRepositories` scans per documentation that way:

> If no base package is configured, it uses the package in which the
>   configuration class resides.
>   https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.java-config

Strange things going on there :)

Comment: Post the code of the entity and the repository, right now it looks like you are missing an annotation in entity.

Comment: Do you have multiple data stores used in you app?

Comment: I have only one data source configured. I use a custom library with a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-data-ldap` ...

Comment: Do you have `@Repository` annotation in your repository?

Comment: No, because for my understanding `@EnableJdbcRepositories` does the job of scanning for them. But nevertheless, putting `@Repository` on them does not do the job - still got `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`

Comment: Found a solution ... see my answer. Thank you for your help everybody.

Answer (score 2):

Should have read the console output with more passion:

> Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface de.thd.dmpk.establishmentmanagement.IEstablishmentRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.

Annotating my entities with `@Table` does the job. Everything´s working after being put onto my entities.

The reason behind this is [DATAJDBC-437](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-437). 
When Spring Data JDBC is used with other Spring Data Modules, Spring Data JDBC used to feel responsible for all reposities, resulting in multiple beans per interface.
In order to avoid that in such a scenario `@Table` annotations are required on the aggregate roots that are to be considered subject of JDBC repositories.

Comment: Not sure but I suspect that this is due to [DATAJDBC-437](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-437), which enforces strict checking when multiple modules for Spring Data are detected (which is the case due to the Spring Data LDAP dependency).

Comment: I added some background to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just some side information on this topic:
if you leave out the `spring-data-ldap` dependency from the `spring-boot-starter-parent` package and replace it with the `spring-ldap-core` then the issue with multiple modules for spring data isn´t there anymore.
So if you just use/depend on the `ldapTemplate` from `spring-ldap-core` then everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `@Repository` at your repositories.

JPABuddy does not do it per default, so I landed here.
These conslusion is already pointed out in the comments, but for the record, we need an answer. :)