# Spring Data JDBC invert OneToMany navigation

Tags: java, spring-data, mapping, one-to-many, spring-data-jdbc

I have an existing data scheme I'm reluctant to change. There are two entities/tables: `parent` and `child`, with child having the foreign key column `parent_id`. It's a 1(parent)-to-n(children) relationship.

Is it possible within Spring Data JDBC to have `Child` class reference `Parent` and not `Parent` have a `Set<Child>` property? Maybe both? (I know it is possible with hibernate, but I'd like to stay with JDBC).

I.e. I want something like this:

```
@Data
public class Parent {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}
```

```
@Data
public class Child {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private Parent parent;
}
```

Somewhat related question: [Spring Data JDBC invert OneToOne navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59090329/spring-data-jdbc-invert-navigation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Data JDBC doesn't offer direct support for a reference from `Child` to `Parent`. If you are modelling `Parent` and `Child` as one aggregate, i.e. with a direct reference, `Parent` must be the aggregate root. So any child gets only accessed the via the `Parent` at all times. Therefore a back reference should be superfluous.

Actually, the desire to have a back reference might be an indication that the two don't really form a single aggregate but separate aggregates and should be modelled as such. See https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/24/spring-data-jdbc-references-and-aggregates

But if you really want your back reference you can easily [establish that in an `AfterLoadCallback`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#entity-callbacks).
For this mark the back reference with the [`@Transient` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/Transient.html) so it doesn't get actually stored in the database.
Then in the `AfterLoadCallback` which will get triggered once for each `Parent` navigate from the `Parent` to each `Child` and set the back reference.